# "...if the data is linearly separable"

Tags: machine-learning, linear-model, feature-selection, kernel-trick

I keep hearing this phrase as a precursor to many algorithms, but I am not sure how exactly one goes about *finding out* if the data is indeed, linearly separable.

Of course, if the data has dimensionality $d\leq3$ we can always go about plotting it I suppose, but what is/are the methods involved exactly in figuring out if/when higher dimensional data ($d \geq 4$) is indeed linearly separable? What techniques are there?

Comment: In most such cases, one runs the algorithm, which will find a linear separator if one exists.

Comment: @whuber This was my suspicion as well. It seems like there is no canonical method besides try and see?

Comment: Finding a solution and testing whether a solution exists are different problems. A linear separator exists if and only if no point in one set lies within the convex hull of the other and *vice versa*. Unfortunately it is not easy to compute convex hulls of $n$ points in high dimensions $d$; the optimal time is $O(n\log n + n^{\lfloor d/2 \rfloor})$. Checking inclusion without explicitly computing the hull is easier, but still complicated: see the discussion at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4901959.

Comment: Practical problems are almost never linearly separable, but linear models often yield acceptable performance. For most methods, linear models can be trained very fast, so fortunately it often doesn't take much computational resources to just try and see as whuber mentioned.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the tour to look at the data. This is a movie of linear projections of the data, so that if the data is linearly separable you should see the groups separate somewhere. Tours are available in [ggobi](http://www.ggobi.org), and the [tourr](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tourr/index.html) package in R. Video examples can be viewed at the Cook & Swayne "Interactive and Dynamic Graphics for Data Analysis" [web site](http://ggobi.org/book/index.html), see the chapter on supervised classification. These videos are in mov format, it is time I put them up on vimeo instead. You can also look at material at [my data mining class site](http://streaming.stat.iastate.edu/~dicook/EDA.and.datamining/) or the [multivariate data analysis site](http://streaming.stat.iastate.edu/~dicook/multivariatelectures/), and videos at [vimeo](https://vimeo.com/user14048736). The tour will work for data up to about 15 dimensions, beyond that it takes too much time to watch to find separations. Combining with projection pursuit can help some. There is also a package called [classifly](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/classifly/index.html) on CRAN which combines tours with data and classification methods. It will make a grid of predictions to see boundaries between classes in high-d.

Comment: (+1) I believe the idea of a tour goes back to Dan Asimov (1985), who has [been a co-author of yours](http://stat.wharton.upenn.edu/~buja/PAPERS/paper-dyn-proj-algs.pdf). I was therefore surprised to see no mention of Asimov at all in your `tourr` documentation.

Comment: Nice. Bookmarked your page. Seems like both of us get a high visualizing data. Some questions: 1) The projections you mention that are being done - what criteria are the vectors being projected against created with? (For example ICA will find a vector that maximizes absolute kurtosis of the data when its projected against it). You mean something similar to this paradigm? 2) My default goto method for visualizing high-D data currently has been SOMs. How do those methods compare to SOMs in general? Many thanks!

Comment: Asimov is referenced in the tourr paper %^)

Comment: There are various versions of the tour. The grand tour essentially randomly generates the linear projections to view. For class data, I would use a projection pursuit guided tour, so the path follows the optimization of a projection pursuit function. We have one that is based on linear discriminant analysis, and another on penalized discriminant analysis. SOM compares some to MDS or PCA. It is a nonlinear projection. I like to generate the SOM net, and view that wrapped in the data in high-d using the tour. Example is on the ggobi web site.